# how can I cache the images coming from other website

Tags: php, caching

I there a way that i can cache the images coming from other websites? I want to have a local copy of the images using cache in PHP so that the site will load faster.

Comment: How are these images coming in? If you just use `<img>` tags in your HTML pointing to off-site URL's, they don't touch your server anyway and caching won't speed anything up.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that caching the images on your server it's going to load faster? In fact, coming from other websites it's usually going to be faster (considering you're using a good image service) because you're going to [Split Components Across Domains](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#split). You can of course  cache your images and create some rules in your server configuration with subdomains to use parallel downloads, but keeping the images across different good domains avoids you from creating all this additional configuration.

If you plan to "load faster" your website, unless your images are coming from a slow server, you can ask other advices here and keep your img configuration. If you plan to cache your images for another reason, then we can have a better answer.

Comment: I uses <img+url of image> But the problem was many images were retrieve in that server so the tendency was to slow down. And I don't have a control on the image server because that is managed by other person. They only gave me a URL of the images. 

Is there anything that I can suggest to them because they said the images on their server is already on cached.

Comment: A user requests an image. You have in cache, you don't call your image server; You don't, you request the image from the image server. Is this what you want?